# How to add different instances of the same object to a LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm designing a shop system here, and it is mainly a media shop, containing items like video games, DVDs and CDs. The issue I am having is that I want to store different instances of the same object, in this case VideoGames, into a linked list. It seems to work, but when I output the List, it only outputs the last item entered into the list and repeats itself for the amount of objects which were supposed to be in the list.

I understand that it is a lot of code to look through, but any help would be greatly appreciaed.

Here is the code for the addVideoGame class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class addVideoGame extends VideoGames implements java.io.Serializable{

public static VideoGames game = new VideoGames();
public static VideoGames eGame = new VideoGames();
public static LinkedList <VideoGames> games = new LinkedList<>();
private static int vgChoice = 0;
public static int vgCount = 0;
public static int vgAmount = 0;

public static void vgMenu(){
    IBIO.output("1: Add a new videogame to the list.");
    IBIO.output("2: View the contents of the list.");
    IBIO.output("3: Save the contents of the list to the local area.");
    IBIO.output("4: Load in data from a local file.");
    IBIO.output("5: Return to the main menu.");
    vgChoice = IBIO.inputInt("Make your choice: ");

    if(vgChoice == 1){
        vgAmount = IBIO.inputInt("How many games would you like to add to the database?: ");
        for(int x = 0; x < vgAmount; x = x + 1){
        VideoGames vg = new VideoGames(); 
        vg.setTitle(IBIO.inputString("Enter the title of the game: "));
        vg.setPublisher(IBIO.inputString("Enter the publisher of the game: "));
        vg.setDeveloper(IBIO.inputString("Enter the developer of the game: "));
        vg.setAgeRating(IBIO.inputInt("Enter the age rating of the game: "));
        vg.setGenre(IBIO.inputString("Enter the genre of the game: "));
        vg.setQuantity(IBIO.inputInt("Enter the available quantity of the game: "));
        game = vg;
        games.add(vg);
        IBIO.output(" ");
        }
        vgMenu();
    } else if(vgChoice == 2){
        IBIO.output("Current amount of games in the list: " + games.size());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(games.toArray()));
        vgMenu();
    } else if(vgChoice == 3){
        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("I:\\IB\\Computer Science\\TheStore\\games.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(game);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            IBIO.output("Data has been saved to: I:\\IB\\Computer Science\\TheStore\\games.txt");
            vgMenu();
        } catch(IOException i){
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if(vgChoice == 4){
        eGame = null;
        for(int x = 0; x < games.size(); x = x + 1){
        try{
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("I:\\IB\\Computer Science\\TheStore\\games.txt");
            ObjectInputStream in =  new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            eGame = (VideoGames) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException i){
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
            IBIO.output("VideoGames class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();;
            return;
        }
        IBIO.output("Object Details: " + eGame.toString());
        vgMenu();
        }
    } else if(vgChoice == 5){
        IBIO.output("Returning to main menu: ");
        AccessMenus.adminMenu();
    } 
}
```

}

If anyone needs them, here are the two interface classes used to navigate the program:

```
public class TheStore {

static String password; //Variable created to hold and check the value of password against the correct value.
public static boolean privilege = false; //Variable created to distinguish the difference between a normal user and a user with administrator privileges.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IBIO.output("Welcome to The Store!");
    IBIO.output("Please make sure that you enter the correct password for your given privileges.");
    password = IBIO.inputString("Enter password: ");
    if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){ //Checks the entered value against the correct value.
        privilege = true; //Sets global boolean value to true, so that admin access is granted.
        IBIO.output(" ");
        AccessMenus.adminMenu();//If password is correct, loads admin menu.
    } else if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("user")){
        privilege = false; //Keeps admin access off, so that unauthorised changes cannot be made.
        IBIO.output(" ");
        AccessMenus.userMenu();//If correct, loads user menu.
    } else {
        IBIO.output("The password is incorrect. Exiting program."); 
        System.exit(1); //If an incorrect password is entered, the program will close.
    } //close else
}//close main
}//close class TheStore
```

And the second one:

```
public class AccessMenus{

    public static int choice;//Variable which will hold the value, which corresponds to an action depending on what value is entered.

    public AccessMenus(){ //Null argument constructor, to set values to 0.
        AccessMenus.choice = 0;
    }

    public AccessMenus(int c){ //Single argument constructor.
        AccessMenus.choice = c;
    }

    public static void userMenu(){
        IBIO.output("1: Sell a product.");
        IBIO.output("2: Register a customer in the Loyalty programme.");
        IBIO.output("3: Stock check.");
        IBIO.output("4: Log out.");
        IBIO.output(" ");
        IBIO.output("Please make your choice: ");
        choice = IBIO.inputInt();
        if(choice == 1){
            //Go to Sales class.
        } else if(choice == 2){
            //Go to CustomerRegister class.
        } else if(choice == 3){
            //Open the StockCheck class.
        } else if(choice == 4){
            IBIO.output("Logging out.");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            IBIO.output("Invalid choice. Returning to menu.");
            userMenu(); //If the value entered does not correspond to any action, the program will treat it as invalid and return to the menu.
        }//close else
    }//close userMenu

    public static void adminMenu(){
        IBIO.output("1: Sell a product.");
        IBIO.output("2: Go to the specific object menus.");
        IBIO.output("3: Stock check.");
        IBIO.output("4: Order more stock.");
        IBIO.output("5: Register a customer in the Loyalty programme.");
        IBIO.output("6: Check Loyalty members.");
        IBIO.output("7: Create databases.");
        IBIO.output("8: Log out.");
        IBIO.output(" ");
        IBIO.output("Please make your choice: ");
        choice = IBIO.inputInt();
        if(choice == 1){
            //Go to Sales class.
        } else if(choice == 2){
          int createChoice = 0;
            IBIO.output("1: Video Games.");
            IBIO.output("2: DVD.");
            IBIO.output("3: CD.");
            createChoice = IBIO.inputInt("Enter choice: ");
            if(createChoice == 1){
                addVideoGame.vgMenu();
            } else if(createChoice == 2){
                //Go to addDVD class.
            } else if(createChoice == 3){
                //Go to addCD class.
            } else {
                IBIO.output("Invalid input.");
                adminMenu();
            }
        } else if(choice == 3){
            //Go to StockCheck class.
        } else if(choice == 4){
            //Go to StockOrder class.
        } else if(choice == 5){
            //Go to CustomerRegister class.
        } else if(choice == 6){
            //Go to LoyaltyCheck class.
        } else if(choice == 7){
            //Go to DatabaseCreation class.
        } else if(choice == 8){
            IBIO.output("Logging out.");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            IBIO.output("Invalid input. Returning to menu.");
            adminMenu();
        } //end else
    }//close AdminMenu
}//close AccessMenus
```

Also, here is the VideoGames object class, containing things like the accessor and mutator methods and primary fields:

```
public class VideoGames implements java.io.Serializable {
    //Instance variables
    public static String title;
    public static int ageRating;
    public static String genre;
    public static String publisher;
    public static String developer;
    public static int quantity;

    public VideoGames(){ //null argument constructor
        VideoGames.title = null;
        VideoGames.ageRating = 0;
        VideoGames.genre = null;
        VideoGames.publisher = null;
        VideoGames.developer = null;
        VideoGames.quantity = 0;
    }//end VideoGames null argument constructor

    public VideoGames(String t, int aG, String g, String p, String d, int q){ //6-argument constructor
      VideoGames.title = t;
      VideoGames.ageRating = aG;
      VideoGames.genre = g;
      VideoGames.publisher = p;
      VideoGames.developer = d;
      VideoGames.quantity = q;
    }//end VideoGames 6-arguement constructor

    public VideoGames(VideoGames game){
        game = new VideoGames();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\nTitle: " + title + " " + "\nPublisher: " + publisher + " " + "\nDeveloper: " + developer + " " + "\nAge Rating: " + ageRating + " " + "\nGenre: " + genre + " " + "\nQuantity: " + quantity + "\n ";
    }

    //Accessor and Mutator methods
public static String getTitle(){
    return title;
    }

public static void setTitle(String t){
        title = t;
    }

public static int getAgeRating(){
        return ageRating;
    }

public static void setAgeRating(int ag){ 
        ageRating = ag;
    }

public static String getGenre(){
        return genre;
    }

public static void setGenre(String g){  
        genre = g;
    }

    public static String getPublisher(){
        return publisher;
    }

    public static void setPublisher(String p){
        publisher = p;
    }

    public static void setDeveloper(String d){
        developer = d;
}
    public static String getDeveloper(){
        return developer;
        }
    public static void setQuantity(int q){
        quantity = q;
        }

    public static int getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
        }//end method setDeveloper
}//end class VideoGames
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean different instances of the same *class*?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wasn't clear enough with that explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field of VideoGames class are all static. Static field belong to Class and only one memory space in method area of JVM. When you execute for loop:

```
VideoGames vg = new VideoGames();
```

you create one VideoGames instance, but when you execute set method:

```
vg.setTitle(IBIO.inputString("Enter the title of the game: "));
   vg.setPublisher(IBIO.inputString("Enter the publisher of the game: "));
   vg.setDeveloper(IBIO.inputString("Enter the developer of the game: "));
   vg.setAgeRating(IBIO.inputInt("Enter the age rating of the game: "));
   vg.setGenre(IBIO.inputString("Enter the genre of the game: "));
   vg.setQuantity(IBIO.inputInt("Enter the available quantity of the game: "));
```

the data you receive will be set to the static field in method area. The value you set previous will be covered by the value you set following. When you print the value of list. You will get value from the static field in method area.

So, 
    but when I output the List, it only outputs the last item entered into the list and repeats itself for the amount of objects which were supposed to be in the list.

Hope to help you. 
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Thank you! It was the fact that the fields were static which was causing the unwanted repetition!

Answer (score 1):

There is too much code for me to properly go through but it sounds like (and a quick scan seemed to confirm) you are only creating one `VideoGames` object. Whenever you change any fields within that object it changes the field in that single object.

You then add that same `VideoGames` object multiple times to the list, but these are all separate references to the same object.

Instead `VideoGames` should be called `VideoGame` and contain the data for one game you should then create a `new VideoGame()` and set it up each time you add one to the list.

Remember the list only contains references to objects, not objects themselves.

Each `VideoGames` object is like a house on a street. At the moment you build one house and keep painting the door on that house different colours instead of building multiple houses and painting the door on each house a different colour.

Your list is just a list of addresses when you add the same house 4 times the list just repeats the same address.

So you were doing:

Build a house in plot 1

1. Paint house door blue
2. Write down plot 1 in a list
3. Paint house door green
4. Add plot 1 to the list again
5. Paint house door red
6. Add plot 1 to the list again

Now you go down the list, you see three entries - but when you go and look at the door colour they all say red.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I don't think that's it. See the line `VideoGames vg = new VideoGames();` in the for loop when adding to the list

Comment: Hmm, true. As I said there was too much code for me to look through it properly. It still explains the symptoms though so could be happening somewhere else in his code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using static members in your VideoGames -class.
The value of this affects all objects, e.g.

```
 public class X {
   public static int y;X() { }
   public 
}
X x1 = new X();
x1.y = 1;
X x2 = new X();
x2.y = 2;
System.out.println("x1.y" + x1.y); // 2
System.out.println("x2.y" + x2.y); // 2
```

Comment: static members are not object members but class members. They have a different type of linking and are handled in different parts of the memory layout of an object. For any given class X the static member y has exactly one value for all instances of that class.